# "to the point where" vs "as to which"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I have two sentences:

- I ran long distances **to the point where** I hurt my left knee.
- I ran long distances **as to which** I hurt my left knee.

What I'm trying to see that I was running heavily which caused a harm to my left knee. Which one of these two sentences above (assume that two expressions are correct) does describe this better?

Comment: Pick the first. Your second sample sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Lawrence Is there any subtle difference between until and "to the point where"?

Comment: Yes. In your sample sentence, "to the point where" gives the impression that the running caused the injury; "until" doesn't - unless you change "*I* hurt" to "*it* hurt".

Comment: @Lawrence I think you answered my question. You might want to add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the first, with "*to the point*". The second sentence doesn't really make sense.

> **it’s getting to the stage/point where** *phrase*
>   used for saying that a situation has reached a very bad stage
>   *Things are getting to the point where we can’t stand to be in the same room.*
>   [- Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-s-getting-to-the-stage-point-where)

The phrase *to the point where* gives the impression that the running caused the injury. This uses the term *point* in the following sense:

> **point** *noun*
>   3.1 A particular moment in time or stage in a process.
>   ‘from this point onward, the teacher was completely won over’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/point)